# Adjective declension with certain pronouns, determiners

Tags: adjective, declension, determiners

Most opinions for DaFS content consist of ‘manche’ and ‘solche’ and similar determiners are put into the der-word category (without any flexibility).
“Manche schönen Bäume” while other sources split der-like determiners into those taking weak and strong endings for the following adjectives.
Especially, “manch/einig/folgend/viel/wenig etc.”  are recommended strong endings:

> Manche/einige schöne Bäume

However, colloquially and in Duden online the case for manche is somewhat varied with no concrete rule, offering both strong and weak.

Is there a more standard rule that will be correct regarding these types of pronoun/adjective? Or if there are other words/situations in which there is a variation in Beugung?

Comment: What is DaFS? And what is a der-word?

Comment: DaFS = Deutsch als FremdSprache?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can vary, and many of these words have their very own "rules" for inflection of the following adjective, which in reality, barely anyone follows all the time.

For manche, it is like this usually:
With a noun in plural, you can choose between parallel (strong) inflection and weak inflection.

> Manche schöne Bäume.   (parallel/strong)
> Manche schönen Bäume.  (weak)

After manch, it is always strong:

> Manch schöne Bäume.  (strong)

No other word has these same rules. "Viele" has its own rules as well. And so on.

You can find a full list in Duden Grammar on page 954 if you really want to master it.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a more standard rule

No. At least I don't see any system to it.

> <strike>manche/einige schöne Bäume</strike>

That's wrong. It must be either

> mancher/ein solcher schöner Baum

> manche/solche schönen Bäume

or

> manch ein/solch ein schöner Baum

> manch/solch schöne Bäume

With *wenig*, it's

> ein wenig schöner Baum

> wenig schöne Bäume

> wenige schöne Bäume

als with other adverbs that may both be used for quantity and quality.

Any of this does **not** apply to *einig/folgend/viel*